# How to create strongly typed list class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, constructor, foreach, instance, generic-list

I hate to admit this but I am new to object oriented programming in VB.NET. I have a class object called Subscriber.vb which works OK but I'd like to create a "set" or list of these objects. Could someone please help me leverage the following code to create a list of the subscribers so a "consumer" could loop through this list of subscribers? Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Class Subscriber
Public Sub New(ByVal theSubscriberID As Int32)
    Dim sConnDatabase As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DatabaseConnString").ConnectionString
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(sConnDatabase)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Try
    cmd = New SqlCommand("GetSubscriberInfo_v", connection)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubscriberID", theSubscriberID)
    connection.Open()
    Dim objReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Do While objReader.Read()
        SetObjectData(objReader)
    Loop
    objReader.Close()
    connection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw
End Try
End Sub
Private Sub SetObjectData(ByVal theObjReader As SqlDataReader)
    Try
        Me._ID = Convert.ToInt32(theObjReader("SubscriberID"))
        Me._NameForLogon = theObjReader("SubscriberName").ToString()
        Me._NameInFull = theObjReader("SubscriberNameFull").ToString()
        Me._DaysUntilExpired = Convert.ToInt32(theObjReader("DaysUntilExpired"))
        Me._SignupDate = theObjReader("SignupDate")
        Me._ExpirationDate = theObjReader("ExpirationDate")
        Me._SubscriberPhone = theObjReader("SubscriberPhone").ToString()
        Me._MostRecentRenewal = theObjReader("MostRecentRenewal")
        Me._CumulativeRevenue = Convert.ToDecimal(theObjReader("CumulativeRevenue"))
        Me._NumberOfRenewals = theObjReader("NumberOfRenewals")
        Me._SubscriptionStatusCode = theObjReader("SubscriptionStatusCode")
        Me._SubscriptionStatus = theObjReader("SubscriptionStatus").ToString()
        Me._NotificationStatusCode = theObjReader("NotificationStatusCode")
        Me._NotificationStatus = theObjReader("NotificationStatus")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

I did not show the getters and setters. This has to be restricted to Visual Studio 2008 unfortunately. For a few reasons, we cannot upgrade this environment.

What would be the best practice here? Add a Public Class SubscriberList to the Subscriber.vb file or should it be a separate file? More importantly, I am stuck on how to take what I have an create a proper list. Then the caller would create an instance of the SubscriberList object. Please help me get started. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is what I came up with thanks to your idea (I'm thinking of adding some overloaded constructors which might filter the data some various ways...would that be a good practice?):

```
    Public Class SubscriberList
Public Sub New()
    Dim sConnDatabase As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DatabaseConnString").ConnectionString
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(sConnDatabase)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim oSubscriberList As New List(Of Subscriber)
    cmd = New SqlCommand("GetSubscriberInfo_v", connection)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    connection.Open()
    Dim objReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Do While objReader.Read()
        Dim id As Integer = objReader("SubscriberID")
        Dim s As Subscriber = New Subscriber(id)
        oSubscriberList.Add(s)
    Loop
    objReader.Close()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

New error trying to use:

```
Dim allSubscribers As New SubscriberList
For Each Subscriber In allSubscribers
                       ' allSubscribers is not declared
Next
```

Why not declared ? Confused rookie mistake I am sure...

**EDIT (Number 2):**
Changed name from SubscriberList to Subscribers plural & got this working (see below) - but I am very puzzled by the advice to remove the database connection and query from the constructor(s) and place in separate class(es). I was picturing adding overloaded constructors to Subscriber (and Subscribers). I cannot imagine how the constructors of each would get their respective data.

```
    Public Class Subscribers
    Implements IEnumerable(Of Subscriber)
#Region "properties"
    Public List As New List(Of Subscriber)
#End Region
Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of Subscriber) _
                    Implements IEnumerable(Of Subscriber).GetEnumerator
    Return List.GetEnumerator()
End Function
Private Function GetEnumerator1() As IEnumerator _
                    Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
    Return List.GetEnumerator()
End Function
Public Sub New()
    Dim sConnDatabase As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DatabaseConnString").ConnectionString
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(sConnDatabase)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Subscriber_v", connection)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    connection.Open()
    Dim objReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Do While objReader.Read()
        Dim id As Integer = objReader("SubscriberID")
        Dim s As Subscriber = New Subscriber(id)
        List.Add(s)
    Loop
    objReader.Close()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB you can make a list of a custom object.

`dim oSubscriberList as new List(of Subscriber)`

Then you can instantiate new subscribers and add them to the list

`oSubscriberList.add('add object here')`

This is probably the most simple, quick and dirty way to handle it.  You can also create a separate class to create a collection of your object.  "Best" practices, if you want to follow SOLID programming principles and use test driven development, would point you towards making a separate collection class to deal with it, but it isnt necessary.

EDIT: as per comment below

You dont need to create a subscriberlist class.  Just create a regular list of Subscribers and add them to the list as so.  Do this where you are wanting to create this list (form load, some event, etc.)

```
Dim oSubscriberList as NEW List(of Subscriber)

Dim sConnDatabase As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DatabaseConnString").ConnectionString
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(sConnDatabase)
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Subscriber_v", connection)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
connection.Open()
Dim objReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

while objReader.Read()
    oSubscriberList.Add(New Subscriber(objReader("SubscriberID"))
end while

'additional cleanup steps here
```

Then you can just iterate over you list as so:

```
For each sub as Subscriber in oSubscriberList
    'do something
Next
```

Comment: Instead List it is possible to use other class from System.Collections.Generic which can be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Will try to press forward as you suggest.

Comment: @Mertis-thank you! Please see my EDIT where I added my interpretation. I wonder if this is good practice. My consuming code would in this case create an instance of SubscriberList() and go directly into a For Each. Or would it be better to skip this class and have the consuming web app and console app deal with declaring their own list(of Subscriber) and building the list via the .add method.

Comment: You are doing too many things in the subscriberlist class.  It should do one thing, and that is to keep track of a list of subscribers.  Connecting to your database and executing a query should be done outside of this class.  Now beyond that, you dont actually need to create a custom class for this really.  It is redundant to create this custom list class, and then use the List(of Subscriber) within it, when you can do all of it without creating this extra class.

Comment: @Mertis - I certainly get the "spirit" of what you say just above but I just can't quite get how this should be done more "properly". Even though I now have it working adequately - allowing the caller to iterate over the list with something like: For Each s in allSubs .. Next - I notice the code I posted above in Edit Number 2 reads in all the subscribers and then for each subscriber in the Do While loop it hits the database again for each individual subscriber! Works, but I know it is not good practice. Any final thoughts?

Comment: I added some additional code and comments in an edit. hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Mertis - thanks again; I removed the extra DB hit by using the constructor that accepts a SQLDataReader: Dim s As Subscriber = New Subscriber(objReader). Yet I still would appreciate greater clarity on your comment: "Connecting to your database and executing a query should be done outside of this class". Where would a Subscribers collection class get it's data?

Comment: Take a look at the additional code i posted.  Im not even using a "subscribers" class.  Im just creating a list of subscriber.  If you do want to keep using a subscribers class, just instantiate it, make your db connection and get the data, create a new subscriber for each entry in the data table and add it to the subscribers object.

Comment: @Mertis - thank you for the clarification. I think I am doing exactly that now in my Subscribers class. You are great to hang in there with my rookie statements and questions.